# List to Dictionary<Key, List<Value>> - C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a List and MyClass is:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public Guid NoticeID { get; set; }
    public Guid TypeID { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, how do i convert this list into a `Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>>`, where the dictionary key is the GUID from the `TypeID` property, and the value is a list of all the `NoticeID` values corresponding to that `TypeID`. I have tried like so:

```
list.GroupBy(p => p.TypeID).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.ToList())
```

but this returns a `Dictionary <Guid, List<MyClass>>`, and I want a `Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>>`.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "but this returns a ` <Guid<List<MyClass>>`. What GUID are you trying to get as a value?

Comment: It's obvious that TypeID is the first Guid in Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>> and NoticeID is the second... I mentioned in the linq clause

Comment: It's not *really* obvious, given that you didn't actually state it. We could infer it, but it would have been a better question if you'd stated that explicitly, and also specified "a `Dictionary<Guid, List<MyClass>>`" instead of just "a <Guid, List<MyClass>>`. Will edit your question to show you what I mean - I think you'll agree afterwards that it's clearer.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience then. I thought it was obvious

Comment: @reresm: You are talking to Jon Skeet and he is helping you solve a problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, when you group you can specify the value you want for each element of the group:

```
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(p => p.TypeID, p => p.NoticeID)
                     .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.ToList());
```

However, I would strongly consider using a lookup instead of a dictionary:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(p => p.TypeID, p => p.NoticeID);
```

Lookups are much cleaner in general:

- They're immutable, whereas your approach ends up with lists which can be modified
- They express in the type system exactly what you're trying to express (one key to multiple values)
- They make looking keys up easier by returning an empty sequence of values for missing keys, rather than throwing an exception

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to an incredibly clever and convenient type - can confirm for anyone still using dictionaries of lists like this that this approach is vastly more fit for purpose